# How to get text element from a Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I am parsing some XML structure `item` which looks as follows:

```
<customfield id="customfield_10004" key="com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float">
    <customfieldname>Yada yada</customfieldname>
    <customfieldvalues>
        <customfieldvalue>8.0</customfieldvalue>
    </customfieldvalues>
</customfield>
```

in the following manner:

```
puts item.xpath(".//customfield[@id='customfield_10004']").css('customfieldvalue')
```

This returns `<customfieldvalue>8.0</customfieldvalue>` of class `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`.

How can I get the inner value (8.0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text` method is probably what you want:

```
item.xpath("//customfield[@id='customfield_10004']//customfieldvalue").text
```

Or with CSS selectors:

```
item.css("#customfield_10004 customfieldvalue").text
```

Comment: Your first one returns all customfields with that id, not only the contained in item. It returns nothing when I use `.//` instead of `//`. The second one does not work.

Comment: Alright looks like I just have a lot of empty values. When I print `.xpath(".//customfield[@id='customfield_10004']").search('customfieldvalue').text` if it is not equal to empty string I see values printed to standard out. Thanks!